# How to change Path for TCL_LIBRARY and TK_LIBRARY in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, matplotlib, path, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've installed matplotlib for Python in Windows 10 but it kept searching for `tcl` and `tk` files in the wrong directory. How can I change it's path? Tried adding the right path in the `Path` under `System Variables` but didn't seems to change anything. Actually, I am not that familiar with Windows (forced to use it by my lecture), so I will be very grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TCL_LIBRARY` and `TK_LIBRARY` environment variables are separate environment variables, not part of the `PATH`, so you [set them in the usual way](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10). Ideally you wouldn't need to set them at all, as the installations of Tcl and Tk should have the correct value baked into them, but Python often seems to set some weird things for historical reasons.